# You should say "sprung to someone" or "sprung onto someone?"

Tags: word-choice

Example sentence:

> Mary sprung to Nana and seized her by the arms.

A native English speaker changed that to sprung onto (I think the person is from Britain). However, Googles gives me more results with "sprung to X."

Comment: Can you include links to your google searches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The anonymous native English speaker you mention might find it hard to justify the change.

**Sprung** (in my experience) used to be just the past participle of the verb **to spring**.

But, as in your example, it is now often used in the past tense as an alternative to the usual past tense, **sprang**.

To **spring to someone** is an unusual phrase although it's perfectly correct.

To **spring to** is most often used in the sense of *springing to attention* or *springing into action*.

There is no reason to change it to **spring onto** (or **spring on to**) unless you want to say that Mary literally jumped on top of Nana, which seems most unlikely.

I note that **sprung** is also used in some circles to mean **infatuated** although it does not appear to be used in this sense in your example.

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/sprung

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sprung